# C++ RedisClient : how does RedisValue.toInt() work?

Tags: c++, redis, redisclient

This is about [RedisClient](https://github.com/nekipelov/redisclient), which is a C++ client.

I know that you can't store integers in Redis (that are internally converted).

RedisSyncClient::command itself does not support integers as RedisBuffer can't be initialized with int, so:

`redis->command("SET", "mykey", 1);`

won't compile (you need to add numbers as string).

However RedisValue can be initialized with int (not sure when it is used) and it contains a public "toInt()" method:

`redis->command("SET", "mykey", "1");
 result = redis->command("GET", "mykey");
 cout << "INT: " << result.toInt() << " , STR: " << result.toString() << endl;`

> INT: 0 , STR : 1

At first I thought that internally strings were being converted to int, but it always return "0". Testing "RedisValue.isInt()" it seems it fails to recognize numbers as it returns "false".

- What is the intention of "toInt()" if numbers are only seen (by this library) as strings?
- Am I using it incorrectly?
- Is this a work-in-progress feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now things make sense to me...
It seems that it may be used for redis responses like:

`result = redis->command("EXISTS", "mykey");
 cout << "? " << result.isInt() << endl;`

> ? 1

In this case toInt() works as expected.

I just need to look into redis documentation and see which commands return int. It is not designed to be used with "normal" values.

(sorry to answer my own question, I would be happy to accept other answers if they cover things I missed out).